# Code running on Google Colab notebook not showing output on its Github copy

Tags: python, pandas, github, google-colaboratory

I am using Pandas to read a CSV file. It is running normally on Google Colab notebook, but after I saved its copy on my Github repository, the code's output is not showing.

[Google Colab Code running properly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sh_fOutRJ-bnWg8_nKxbk1FIgJtMExu8/view?usp=sharing)

[The same code's output not showing on Github](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SoUZj2jg8ffcXJ6Mv4uELXqOADSb3UPr/view?usp=sharing)

Sorry for not uploading images directly. Tried twice and failed ._.